# Master/application layouts with Erlydtl

Tags: erlang, django-templates

What's a nice way to do master/application layouts with Erlydtl? With master/application layout I mean separating the main page layout template from template with the pagecontent, but rendering them as one. Think Ruby on Rails application layouts or ASP.NET Master Pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like:

**main.dtl**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page.dtl**

```
{% extends "main.dtl" %}

{% block content %}
Here's my content
{% endblock %}
```